# How to play all media in the library in Foobar2000?

Tags: music, media-player, foobar2000

I configured my Foobar2000 to monitor some folders for media. How to play those folders? I'm not finding the button....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a playlist populated by the media library:

**By the Album List panel:** `Library > Album List` (If the album list panel is in your layout it should flash some times, if not a new window appears.)

[image]

You could right click the branch and choose the appropriate action (e.g. Add to current playlist / Send to new playlist). The highest branch is **All Music**... If the "library viewer selection playlist" is enabled (look at Molly Answer) the playlist will be populated when you select a branch.

You could also change double & middle click actions, and tweak the different views with [the title formatting syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Titleformat_Reference) in `File > Preferences > Media Library > Album List`

**By the Search panel:** `Library > Search` (If the search panel is in your layout it should flash some times, if not a new window appears)

[image]

Here you could use [the query syntax](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Query_syntax) and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send your search in the actual playlist and play it. Use Right Click in the list for other options... `%path% PRESENT` finds **all your library**

**Additionaly:** with these two panels you could create **AutoPlaylist** (auto populated): use the three dots in Search and right click in Album List.

And the component [Facets](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_facets) could interest you.

Answer (score 5):

Did you enable the **Library Viewer Selection Playlist**?

[image]

Then all your tracks in the monitored folders should be shown in a play list called "Library Viewer Selection" (you can rename it if you want).

[image]

Comment: The Library Viewer Selection Playlist is dependent of the Library Viewer: e.g. Album List, Facets...

Comment: The problem it is that the Library Viewer Selection starts empty, it only was populated after I used the `%path% PRESENT` search

Comment: @Jader Dias - well, it will be automatically populated (with all songs in the default order , album/artist, IIRC) once you open the Album List and close it again.